# Infiniband + KVM

Tags: centos, kvm, infiniband

despite quite a long search for days, I could not find any good information about the following - though I think, I can not be the first to have this problem: We are working on a high-performance-cluster with MATLAB, MPI and Infiniband. This setting has been working quite well over the last years. But to reach more flexibility and easier maintaining we are thinking about virtualizing the calculation nodes with KVM.

Now I have the big problem of getting Infiniband "into" my virtual machine. I do not only want to passthrough the PCI-Interface but build something corresponding to a ethernet bridge which I can virtually connect to my machine(s) on my host. I found some sources that talk about this - but not how to install/configure IB. Does anyone out there have an idea how to this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not exactly a programming question. It might be a better fit for http://Serverfault.com. As an option you could consider bridging IPoIB interface to virtual machines which might be easier than virtualizing the InfiniBand adapter.

Comment: Give a try to SoftRoCE which run infiniband protocol i.e. RDMA over Converged ethernet simulated on classic ethernet cards or if you can buy a RoCE enabled ethernet card, then you can directly install infiniband stack(OFED Stack).

Comment: You can use EoIPoIB (Ethernet over IPoIB) so it would be easy to use vswitch to connect the IB interface seamlessly to the VM. Please note however, that the results wouldn't be as good as with path-through.